# How to do delete button that delete one cell in collection view and row in sqlite in xamarin?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

How to delete cell in collection view and row in sqlite?
I need to get from collection view primary key and i dont know how.
I want to have delete button on every view cell.
I have ended up with this:

```
public void RemovePlane()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    db.Delete<Airplane>();
}
```

xaml:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollectionView" Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedPlane}">                
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Margin="0">
                <Frame Padding="0" BackgroundColor="#00d2ff" Margin="0, 65, 0, 0" CornerRadius="30">
                    <StackLayout Padding="20">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Airline}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUrl}" HeightRequest="200"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Plane, StringFormat='Plane: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Airline, StringFormat='Airline: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Livery, StringFormat='Livery: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Registration, StringFormat='Reg: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Airport, StringFormat='Airport: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='Date: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Comment, StringFormat='Comment: {0}'}" TextColor ="White" FontSize="15"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Button Text="Delete" CornerRadius="30" Margin="10, 0" HeightRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="deleteButton"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<CollectionView.EmptyView>                    
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="30" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="No planes to display" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.45, 300, 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>                        
        <Button Text="Import Plane" WidthRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#00d2ff" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="30" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.55, 280, 70" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>                    
</CollectionView.EmptyView>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign a handler for your button

```
<Button Text="Delete" Clicked="RemovePlane" ... />
```

in your handler

```
public void RemovePlane(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var plane = (Airplane)button.BindingContext;

    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    db.Delete<Airplane>(plane);

    // finally, either refresh your ItemsSource from your db
    // or if you are using an ObservableCollection just remove
    // it from the collection
}
```

Comment: `var plane = (Plane)button.BindingContext;` Throws me specified cast is not valid error

Comment: what is the type of your ItemsSource?  You need to cast to the appropriate type - I had to guess that `Plane` was the correct type because it is not shown in your code

Comment: It sqlite db with name Airplane

Comment: then use `Airplane` instead of `Plane`

Comment: Still doesnt work it writes: cannot store type: Spotter.Models.Airplane on `db.Delete<Airplane>(plane);`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm#deleting-an-object

Comment: I ve tried to use that, please look to new answer. Do you think it can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and and when i refresh it works.
One question it delete whole row? And can it be improved somehow?

```
private void deleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var plane = (Airplane)button.BindingContext;

        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        db.Delete<Airplane>(plane.Id);
    }
```

Comment: This code is @Jason's answer. If it solved your problem you should accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark. If you need further help you should leave a comment. If there are still problems edit your question and explain what the problem is. You can read more here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Comment: It works, thanks @Jason just sharing code for others. I dont want to steal Jason answer :)